# Command (editor.action) to close Completion Modal in monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor

Monaco editor provide a way to trigger the completion modal with `editor.action.triggerSuggest`. Is someone know a way to force closing completion modal ?

In some cases when the expression is Finish : for example when user type ',' or ']' and the suggest modal continue to display results :s

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
this._editor.trigger('editor', 'hideSuggestWidget', []);